# Draw with brush in a straight line in photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

A have a square here.
[image]

I want draw clouds whole of this square. By choosing selection area I just can paint in square area. I need clouds exceed of square borders.

[image]

I need a thing like this. I have painted this by clicking on the page.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what your question is. From your images it looks like you achieved the effect you wanted? Could you clarify if not?

Answer (score 2):

One can paint in a straight line with the Brush tool by shift-clicking. Click in one corner, then shift-click in the next corner, repeating until you shift-click in the first corner.

Answer (score 1):

You make a cloud brush separately by your preferred image of clouds on a file. Save it in brushes. Then use it like any other brushes. 
Following is a link of video on how to make brush using an image in photoshop:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ED7d3fu1qls